# D3.js realtime graph not updating smoothly

Tags: d3.js, path, live, smoothing

I'm getting JSON data do D3 line graph. Next requesting new data after last point and concat() the new data, updating the line and moving to the left on each transition()

I need to recalculate xScale each time to put the new time values and remove the old ones on x-axis. And the x-axis is scrolling to the left smoothly and correctly. But when I start to recalculation the xScale my line path stop smooth translation to the left and just jumping immediately on each update_path(). If I remove xScale.domain(d3.extent(... the path is transitioning smoothly to the left, but don't have the new times on x-axis.

[image]
[image]

```
function update_path(svg,path,dataset,xScale) {
        var last=dataset[dataset.length-1];
        var last_point=last[Object.keys(last)[0]];

        // check new data and put it
        d3.json("data.php?chartID=1&last_point="+last_point).then(function(data) {

            dataset=dataset.concat(data);

            var yScale=d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[Object.keys(d)[1]]; }), 0])
    .range([0, range]);

            xScale.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return new Date(d[Object.keys(d)[0]]); }))

            var translate=dataset[0];
            var translate_point=translate[Object.keys(translate)[0]];

            var prelast=dataset[dataset.length-2];
            var prelast_point=prelast[Object.keys(prelast)[0]];

            var last=dataset[dataset.length-1];
            var last_point=last[Object.keys(last)[0]];

            var prelast_date=new Date(prelast_point);
            var last_date=new Date(last_point);
            var seconds = (last_date.getTime() - prelast_date.getTime());

            var line=prepare_line(xScale,yScale);

            // update x-axis
            var xaxis_call=d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks().tickSize(-height);
            svg.selectAll("g.main_g").selectAll("g.x-axis")
                .transition()
                .duration(seconds)
                .ease(d3.easeLinear)
                .attr("transform", "translate(-"+ xScale(new Date(translate_point))+",100)")
                .call(xaxis_call)

            // update line
            path
                .attr("d", line(dataset))
                .transition()
                .duration(seconds)
                .ease(d3.easeLinear)
                .attr("transform", "translate(-"+ xScale(new Date(translate_point))+")")
                .on('end', function() {
                    update_path(svg,path,dataset,xScale);
                });

            dataset.shift();
        });
    }
```

So how to fix the line path to be updated and to move smoothly to the left at the same time while coming the new data from the right?

Answer (score 0):

I have reordered my code a little bit and also the key in my case for smooth translate was .attr('transform', null) on path object.

```
function update_path(svg,path,dataset,xScale) {
// get last date
var last=dataset[dataset.length-1];
var last_point=last[Object.keys(last)[0]];

// check new data and put it
d3.json("data.php?chartID=1&last_point="+last_point).then(function(data) {

    data=make_dataset(data,data_index); // add some my stuff to dataset object
    dataset=dataset.concat(data);
    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        dataset.shift();
    }
    var translate=dataset[0];
    var translate_point=translate[Object.keys(translate)[0]];

    var prelast=dataset[dataset.length-2];
    var prelast_point=prelast[Object.keys(prelast)[0]];

    var last=dataset[dataset.length-1];
    var last_point=last[Object.keys(last)[0]];

    var prelast_date=new Date(prelast_point);
    var last_date=new Date(last_point);
    var seconds = (last_date.getTime() - prelast_date.getTime());

    var line=prepare_line(xScale,yScale);
    // update x-axis
    var xaxis_call=d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    svg.selectAll("g.main_g").selectAll("g.x-axis")
        .transition()
        .duration(seconds)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .attr("transform", "translate(-"+ xScale(new Date(translate_point))+","+height+")")
        .call(xaxis_call)

    // update line
    path.attr('transform', null)
        .attr("d", line(dataset))
        .transition()
        .duration(seconds)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .attr("transform", "translate(-"+ xScale(new Date(translate_point))+")")
        .on('end', function() {
            // my custom functions for preparing Scales
            var xScale=axis_scaleTime(dataset, width);
            var yScale=axis_scaleLinear_values1(dataset, height);               
            update_path(svg,path,dataset,xScale);
        }); 
});
```

}